# How to access to the data of an object?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I have a function which reads the data from the Firebase. I can read the objects but not the properties.

I try to parse the content but I have an error.

This is the function:

```js
 this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
            this.itemsList = this.afDatabase.list(`oders/${data.uid}`).valueChanges();
            
            console.log(this.itemsList)
            this.itemsList.forEach(data =>{
              console.log(data) // this work
              console.log(data.name) // this doesn't work (undifined in console)
            })
          })
```

My `JSON OBJECT`

```
(14) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {hour: 1567395936608, id: 0, name: "Salami", price: "8"}
1: {hour: 1567395936608, id: 9, name: "Suplémment Fromage", price: "8"}
2: {hour: 1567395936608, id: 4, name: "bolo", price: "8"}
3: {hour: 1567395936608, id: 4, name: "bolo", price: "8"}
4: {hour: 1567395985542, id: 4, name: "bolo", price: "8"}
5: {hour: 1567395985542, id: 0, name: "Salami", price: "8"}
6: {hour: 1567395985542, id: 9, name: "Suplémment Fromage", price: "8"}
7: {hour: 1567397849623, id: 6, name: "Dems", price: "15"}
8: {hour: 1567397849623, id: 0, name: "Salami", price: "8"}
9: {hour: 1567397849623, id: 9, name: "Suplémment Fromage", price: "8"}
10: {hour: 1567398309241, id: 0, name: "Salami", price: "8"}
11: {hour: 1567398309241, id: 9, name: "Suplémment Fromage", price: "8"}
12: {hour: 1567402336588, id: 0, name: "Salami", price: "8"}
13: {hour: 1567402336588, id: 9, name: "Suplémment Fromage", price: "8"}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you see in data ?

Comment: its an array, you want all the names as array?

Comment: I want the acces at 'hour' proprieties of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `data` is an array itself, you need to run another loop

Try like this:

```
this.itemsList.forEach(data =>{
   this.data.forEach(e=>{
       console.log(e.name) 
   })
})
```

or you can do this:

```
this.itemsList[0].forEach(data =>{
    console.log(data.name) 
})
```

Comment: Yes but i can't. I need to wait 4min :)

Answer (score 0):

Using spread operator.

```
[...this.itemsList].forEach(item) {
 console.log(item.hour);
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of spread operator? We can simply use this.itemsList.forEach(item) {
 console.log(item.name);
}

Comment: Since `itemsList` is 2D array instead of using two forEach its better to use one spread operator and one forEach.